# Iterating through a string array and filling a dictionary type with <key, value> as word, occurenceCount --

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dictionary, keyvaluepair

My problem is as follows -

I am creating an array as follows(refer pic --->  https://pasteboard.co/JzJohvs.png) -

I want to count occurrence of words in this array and create an arraylist or a dictionary whichever is suitable.

My code -

```
    public List<Dictionary<string, int>> GetWordCount(string[] myArray)
    {
        try
        {
            var countedObj = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();

            Array.Sort(myArray);

            var counts = myArray.GroupBy(w => w).Select(g => new { Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList();

            for(int index=0; index<counts.Count; index++)
            {
                var item = counts.ElementAt(index);

                var itemkey = item.Word;

                var itemvalue = item.Count;

                countedObj.Add(new Dictionary<string, int>()
                {
                    
                });
            }

            return countedObj;
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            throw exp.InnerException;
        }
    }
```

What I need is to create a dictionary list such as

life, 3
inherent, 2
useful, 1,
educated, 5,
lgitimate, 2
and so on......

basically key value pair type. I'm sure you get what I basically intend to achieve. Something that I can iterate and process later on as per my need. How can I do that? What type of iteration is required? some relevant code suggestions here.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? What results do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: Why do you have a list of dictionaries instead of a single dictionary? I thought you just needed words as keys and their counts as values. What are the other dictionaries in the list for?

Comment: Also, why are you catching an exception and then rethrowing it's inner exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by the words, select the count of each group (which you're already doing), and then turn that into a dictionary with the word as the key and the count as the value:

```
Dictionary<string, int> wordCounts = myArray
    .GroupBy(word => word)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());
```

So the method could be re-written as:

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> GetWordCount(string[] myArray)
{
    return myArray?
        .GroupBy(word => word)
        .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());
}
```

And then sample usage might be:

```
var words = new[] {"one", "two", "two", "three", "three", "three"};

foreach (var item in GetWordCount(words))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} = {item.Value}");
}
```

**Output**

```
one = 1
two = 2
three = 3
```